# How to connect Go application and Apache Solr?

Tags: go

I want connect my Go application and Apache solr

I configured apache Solr manually

```
Path => /home/vtrk/Solr/solr-4.9.1
```

Solr is running perfectly

```
Port : localhost:8983/solr/
```

But I don't know how to connect with my Go application.

How to connect Go application and Apache Solr?

Comment: Solr has an http interface. You can either write the http requests yourself, or try a client library. It's the same as any other language.

Comment: other lang its possible, Im asking its possible in Go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at this library and see if solves your needs

https://github.com/rtt/Go-Solr/